# Cppcheck generate xml dump file

Tags: c++, xml, cppcheck

I'm trying use xml dump file in cppcheck to create my rule. And when I'm look dump file generate when run cppcheck i see tag rawtokens have list file relate and raw data in file.

```
<rawtokens>
<file index="0" name="qtProject/untitled1/teststatistic.cpp"/>
<file index="1" name="qtProject/untitled1/teststatistic.h"/>
```

But I just see raw data fileIndex = 0

```
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="1" column="1" str="#"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="1" column="2" str="include"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="1" column="10" str="&quot;teststatistic.h&quot;"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="4" column="1" str="TestStatistic"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="4" column="14" str="::"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="4" column="16" str="TestStatistic"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="4" column="29" str="("/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="4" column="30" str=")"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="5" column="1" str="{"/>
<tok fileIndex="0" linenr="7" column="1" str="}"/>
</rawtokens>
```

Is there any option in cppcheck to show raw data from all file list in rawtokens ?

Command I generate file dump:
cppcheck --dump teststatistic.cpp

Comment: When I'm look source code cppcheck in file cppcheck.cpp, function checkFile. Seem no option to list all raw data. So how can I change source code to show all raw data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`cppcheck` produces a `.dump` file for each input file listed on the command line. So, when you do `cppcheck --dump teststatistic.cpp`, you get `teststatistic.cpp.dump` as output.

You can do `cppcheck --language=c++ --dump teststatistic.cpp teststatistic.h` to get dump files for both the `.cpp` and `.h` file. Or you can invoke `cppcheck` twice, once for the `.cpp` file and once for the `.h` file. Either way, you can then get the raw data for each input file from the corresponding `.dump` file.

Note that `cppcheck` knows that a `.cpp` file is c++, but does not know that a `.h` file is c++. So, when processing the `.h` file, you must specify the language on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have solve my problem using bash to check all file in folder